# Flask-admin inline modelling passing form arguments throws AttributeError

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

Hi there fellow Flask developers!

In Flask-admin, I currently try to implement inline model editing into my model view. On the model side, I have a simple tree structure that represents a set of content pages. Each node has several child nodes and also several content data models associated with it. The models are named `ContentNode` and `ContentData`.

If I use the `inline_models` property on the node view class as described in the Docs [here](http://flask-admin.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/mod_contrib_sqla/), it seems to work fine at first.

```
# AuthModelView is simply ModelView with user authentification
class ContentNodeModelView(AuthModelView):
    ...

    inline_models = (models.ContentData, )
```

However, as soon as I try to pass properties to the inline form, using

```
inline_models = [(models.ContentData, dict(form_columns=['title', 'text']))]
```

the Flask server gives

```
AttributeError: 'ContentDataForm' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Am I missing something super obvious here? Is there maybe a mistake in the documentation because it sounds like maybe `inline_models` expects a model but gets a dictionary?

I definitely checked that it's the same as in the docs.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: Why editing forms when sending it ? Rebuild your form before publishing !

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Where would I pass the rebuilt form exactly?

Answer (score 9):

You forgot to specify id, which uses for inline-form construction.
Try to add 'id' attribute in:

```
inline_models = [(models.ContentData, dict(form_columns=['id', 'title', 'text']))]
```

Comment: Great answer, can't believe this wasn't in the documentation